# How can i fix this case in reactjs with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

My screen appears an error is "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression". Anyone can help me fix this case.I try to fix that but it's not working

```
import { createSlice , createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk ("posts/getPosts" , 
async (dispatch , getState) => {
    return await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then(res => res.json())


}
)

 const addPostSlice = createSlice({
    name:'add',
    initialState:{
        posts:[],
        status:false
    },
        
    
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [getPosts.pending]:(state ) => {
            state.status = "loading"
        },
        [getPosts.fulfilled]:(state , action) => {
            state.status ="success",
            state.posts = action.payload
        },
        [getPosts.rejected]:(state ) => {
            state.status = "failed"
            
        },
    }



    },
    
 )
const  { reducer} = addPostSlice
export default reducer
```

Comment: Looks like you've got an extra closing bracket down near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error you get. Click **Run code snippet** below.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@4.1.2/dist/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@7.2.6/dist/react-redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.7.1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@1.6.1/dist/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } = RTK;

// ================================================================
// ================================================================

const getPosts = createAsyncThunk ("posts/getPosts" , 
async (dispatch , getState) => {
    return await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then(res => res.json())


}
)

 const addPostSlice = createSlice({
    name:'add',
    initialState:{
        posts:[],
        status:false
    },
        
    
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [getPosts.pending]:(state ) => {
            state.status = "loading"
        },
        [getPosts.fulfilled]:(state , action) => {
            state.status ="success",
            state.posts = action.payload
        },
        [getPosts.rejected]:(state ) => {
            state.status = "failed"
            
        },
    }



    },
    
 )

const  { reducer} = addPostSlice

// ================================================================
// ================================================================

const { useEffect } = React;
const { Table } = ReactBootstrap;
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { configureStore } = RTK;

const store = configureStore({
  reducer:{
    addPosts: reducer
  }
});


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  posts: state.addPosts.posts
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getPosts: () => dispatch(getPosts())
  };
};

const connectToStore = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const Posts = connectToStore((props) => {
  const { posts, getPosts } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Body</th>
          <th>UserId</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {posts.map((p) => (
          <tr key={p.id}>
            <td>{p.id}</td>
            <td>{p.title}</td>
            <td>{p.body}</td>
            <td>{p.userId}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
});

const CounterControl = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={props.inc}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={props.dec}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const StoreProvider = (props) => {
  return <Provider store={store}>{props.children}</Provider>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StoreProvider>
      <Posts />
    </StoreProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```